# how to create many linear models at once and put the coefficients into a new matrix?

Tags: r, loops, apply, linear-regression, coefficients

I have 365 columns. In each column I have 60 values. I need to know the rate of change over time for each column (slope or linear coefficient). I created a generic column as a series of numbers from 1:60 to represent the 60 corresponding time intervals. I want to create 356 linear regression models using the generic time stamp column with each of the 365 columns of data.

In other words, I have many columns and I would like to create many linear regression models at once, extract the coefficients and put those coefficients into a new matrix.

Comment: It's possible to do this if someone is holding a gun to your head, but it is so statistically dirty that you would need to go take a shower and scrub yourself with turpentine soap.

Comment: I am getting the coefficients of each night's change in water table (recharge when ET is negligible)  in order to calculate evapotranspiration using the White Method.

Comment: Perhaps if you analyze the coefficients as a correlated time series this might make sense. The way it was described made me think you were on a search for "significant" time points".

Comment: Thanks for your input - I don't want to do bad statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, statistically this might not be the best possible approach to analyse temporal data. Although, regarding the approach you propose, it is very simple to build a loop to obtain this:

```
Coefs <- matrix(,ncol(Data),2)#Assuming your generic 1:60 column is not in the same object
for(i in 1:ncol(Data)){
Coefs[i,] <- lm(Data[,i]~GenericColumn)$coefficients
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this and it looks like it works. I tried this one because it seemed simple enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
# Fake data
dat = data.frame(x=1:60, y1=rnorm(60), y2=rnorm(60), 
                 y3=rnorm(60))

t(sapply(names(dat)[-1], function(var){
   coef(lm(dat[,var] ~ x, data=dat))
}))

   (Intercept)            x
y1  0.10858554 -0.004235449
y2 -0.02766542  0.005364577
y3  0.20283168 -0.008160786
```

Now, where's that turpentine soap?