# Creating a customised results table from many linear models

Tags: r, regression, lm, summary

I am working in an analytical lab where a lot of data is generated. We do model fitting and are interested in model coefficients (intercept, a, b), r_squared and residual standard error. The number of up to 70 dependant variables (responses) is rather large. I would like to generate from mylms a table where the rows are the responses a to f and the columns the mentioned model parameters.

I was not able to adapt the solutions I found on the net to my case:

- [By selfmade function](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-ecology/2008-May/000062.html)
- [By only calling coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922815/how-to-create-many-linear-models-at-once-and-put-the-coefficients-into-a-new-mat)

A part of the solution is surely summary(mylms) where the parameters are stored.

Here is the simplified example I would like to find a solution to:

```
#To generate a dataset
x <- c(1:30)
x2 <- x*x
a <- x2
b <- jitter(a, factor=10)
c <- jitter(b, factor=30)
d <- jitter(c, factor=40)
e <- jitter(d, factor=50)
f <- jitter(e, factor=60)
z <- cbind(a,b,c,d,e,f)

# The matrix y are the responses of x
y <- as.matrix(z)

# Define the weights for the regression
w <- 1/x

# create linear models
mylms <- lm(y~x+x2, weights=w)
```

Comment: so you have up to 70 columns, where the fields are the coefficients? And how many rows do you have? Always 6 (A-F)?

Comment: Check out the broom package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html

Comment: Actually, in my response matrix y the number of colums will change. It might be 30, but it might also be 70 or 15. The number of columns in matrix y will equal the number of rows in my result table. But the result table will always have 5 rows: intercept, a, b, r_squared and residual standard error.

Comment: When I use glance I get this error:  glance does not support multiple responses   I managed to get the coefficients by the tidy function! :)

Comment: Rob, could you provide the code for the solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
mylms$residuals
```

or to get the range of the residuals for example:

```
apply(mylms$residuals,2,range)
```

or to get the quantiles for example:

```
apply(mylms$residuals,2,quantile,seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1))
```

Comment: Actually I am looking for the residual standard error, not each residual itself!

Comment: I found the solution

    Rest.stabw <- NULL
    R2 <- NULL
    for(i in 1:l/2){
     Rest.stabw[i] <- summary(mylms)[[i]]$sigma R2[i]  <- summary(a.lm)[[i]]$r.squared
}